# How to log to web page in node.js?

Tags: node.js, logging

There is a simple way in a node.js application to log and display the result in real time in an html web page?

I have to build a 'monitor' for my application and I would like to see what is happening consulting a well formatted web page. I can display the page with express

```
app.use(express.static('monitor'));
```

but I am not sure about the best way to send data to it.

Comment: WebSockets ([Socket.io](http://socket.io/)) allow bi-directional communication. If you want something simple, you can easily implement all the required logic by yourself. If you're working on a bigger project where a lot of things are dynamic and real-time, consider using [Meteor](http://meteor.com) for example, which makes working with real-time data changes pretty easy (only such framework I know about).

Comment: Try to use the [Scribe.js](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/Scribe.js?files=1). Live demo is [here](https://bluejamesbond.github.io/Scribe.js/)

Comment: Scribe.js s totally the solution. If you convert the comment to a proper answer I would like to accept it.

Comment: @SashaGrievus Yeaahh, I answered. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To monitor logs in real time, you can try to use the [Scribe.js](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/Scribe.js?files=1). Live demo is [here](https://bluejamesbond.github.io/Scribe.js/)

[image]